# Span elements not in-flow when between spaces?

Tags: html, css, dom

Why do empty `<span>` elements not conform to flow when sandwiched between `<span>` elements with spaces?

Here's an example:

```html
<span>h</span><span>e</span><span>l</span><span>l</span><span>o</span><span class="space"> </span><span class="empty"></span><span class="empty"></span><span class="empty"></span><span class="space"> </span><span>t</span><span>h</span><span>e</span><span>r</span><span>e</span>
```

Above, we have some `<span>` elements forming a phrase. But I've put some empty elements in between two spaces. The result takes the empty elements out of flow. If you use the debugging tools you'll see that `span.empty` elements are no longer in-flow, and are considered 0px, 0px wide.

Doing the same without the wrapping space elements, and the empty elements are back in-flow:

```html
<span>h</span><span>e</span><span>l</span><span>l</span><span>o</span><span class="empty"></span><span class="empty"></span><span class="empty"></span><span>t</span><span>h</span><span>e</span><span>r</span><span>e</span>
```

Can anyone explain why this is? I'm using Chrome 45.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, browsers will collapse a sequence of spaces into a single space. I believe the main reason behind this is so that the markup can be indented for maintainability without effecting the final rendered output.

In both examples the `.empty` `span`s do not contain anything and are set to the default `display: inline;` which means they will not take up any horizontal space. The difference between the two examples is what surrounds them:

- In the first example, they are between two spaces and are therefore collapsed out of existence. You will get the same outcome if the `.empty` `span`s contained a space
- In your second example they are surrounded by characters so the white-space collapse does not come into effect

Testing in a couple of different browsers, this appears to be how Chrome decides to display collapsed elements. Firefox and Opera do things differently and handle the `.empty` `span`s in both your examples in the same way (by not showing them at all).

Comment: Great answer. Also, useful to know what Firefox and Opera are rendering. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use non-breaking space:

```
<span>&nbsp;</span>
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried that and it works, but it doesn't really answer the question "Can anyone explain why this is?". The reason I don't want to use non-breaking-spaces is because I want the spaces to continue to break.

Comment: If you don't use non-breaking space then browser will ignore for the space.

Comment: Sorry, but this still doesn't explain why.

Answer (score 0):

`span` tags are `display:inline` by default but are affected by `white-space` in the code.

White-space has no size of it's own but it does render